# Spring Security custom UserDetailsService and custom User class

Tags: java, spring, security, jpa, spring-security

I am trying to save additional data in de user principal object.

What i did was:

implement the "UserDetails" interface to my existing user class where my additional data is saved ( like email address etc. ).

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {
```

Then i created a UserDetailsService implementation:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDAO.findOneByUsername(username);
        if (user == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("username " + username
                    + " not found");

        System.out.println("---------------------> FOUND ------------->"
                + user.getEmail());

        return user;
    }

}
```

Last step was to add the UserDetailsService in my Security configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;



@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
// ...

}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
// ...
}

@Override
protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return userDetailsService;
}
```

I see in my console that "loadUserByName" gets called twice ( because of the "Found" output ).

When i try to access the principal object in my controller ->

```
System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication().getPrincipal());
```

I dont get my additional data.
When i try to cast it to my User object i get a could not cast exception.

Is there anything I am missing??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok. My problem was hidden in the code i didnt post.

I thought this detailsService is only to get additional details but it is used for the login itself.

I had "jdbcAuthentication" configured additionally and spring seemed to use this always.

Now that i only got the detailsService configured everything works fine.

edit.:

so i only had to delete this code:

```
auth.jdbcAuthentication() .dataSource(dataSource)
     * .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder) .usersByUsernameQuery(
//   ....
```

And now it also works with my code in the question above.

Answer (score 1):

Create Extention class:

```
public class CustomUserDetails extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User{

    private User user;

    public CustomUserDetails(User user, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(user.getName(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
        this.user = user;
    }

    public CustomUserDetails(User user, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(user.getName(), user.getPassword(), enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

Than add it to UserDetailsService:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
    UserDetails userDetails = null;
    User user = userService.getByLogin(login);
    userDetails = new CustomUserDetails(user,
                true, true, true, true,
                getAuthorities(user.getRole()));

    return userDetails;
}
```

Get it!

```
 (CustomUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

Comment: That didnt change anything.

Btw. your last code snippet gives me:
"java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to ..........CustomUserDetails"

Comment: can you debug your app and say what class will return `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` ?

Comment: class org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User