# Reload users.properties at runtime spring

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, properties

I'm running a project using Spring MVC and Spring Security and I'm using external file for authentication :

```
    <user-service id="userDetailsService" properties="users.properties"/>
```

But I'm forced to restart the server when I change the properties file. So, I was wondering if there's a solution, a tag or parameter, that I can put on the tag "user-service" to specify a timeout for reloading the cache.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You are using the InMemory Provider and specifying the properties file option. The InMemory provider does not provide an option to reload the properties file.

You can either move to a different provider, like the daoAuthenticationProvider to store the users in a database, or implement your own UserDetailsService such that it reloads the properties file as needed.

You can find the JavaDoc for UserDetailService here:
http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html

There is an example of creating a custom UserDetalService here:
[Spring Security custom UserDetailsService and custom User class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383286/spring-security-custom-userdetailsservice-and-custom-user-class)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please give me the name of the class that Spring use for properties so I won't start from scratch.

Comment: In the answer, there is a link to an example that shows exactly how to do it. You need to implement the 'UserDetailsService' interface. The link gives you a concrete example for this.