# How to enable Bearer authentication on Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, kotlin, spring-security-oauth2

What I am trying to achieve is:

- users, authorities, clients and access tokens stored in a database (i.e. MySQL) accessed via jdbc
- API exposes endpoints for you to ask "can I have an OAuth2 bearer token? I know the client ID and secret"
- API lets you access MVC endpoints if you supply a Bearer token in your request header

I got pretty far with this — the first two points are working.

I was not able to use a completely default OAuth2 setup for my Spring Boot application, because the standard table names are already in-use in my database (I have a "users" table already, for example).

I constructed my own instances of JdbcTokenStore, JdbcClientDetailsService, and JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices manually, configured them to use the custom table names from my database, and set up my application to use these instances.

---

So, here's what I have so far. I can ask for a Bearer token:

```bash
# The `-u` switch provides the client ID & secret over HTTP Basic Auth 
curl -u8fc9d384-619a-11e7-9fe6-246798c61721:9397ce6c-619a-11e7-9fe6-246798c61721 \
'http://localhost:8080/oauth/token' \
-d grant_type=password \
-d username=bob \
-d password=tom
```

I receive a response; nice!

```json
{"access_token":"1ee9b381-e71a-4e2f-8782-54ab1ce4d140","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"8db897c7-03c6-4fc3-bf13-8b0296b41776","expires_in":26321,"scope":"read write"}
```

Now I try to *use* that token:

```bash
curl 'http://localhost:8080/test' \
-H "Authorization: Bearer 1ee9b381-e71a-4e2f-8782-54ab1ce4d140"
```

Alas:

```json
{
   "timestamp":1499452163373,
   "status":401,
   "error":"Unauthorized",
   "message":"Full authentication is required to access this resource",
   "path":"/test"
}
```

This means (in this particular case) that it has fallen back to *anonymous* authentication. You can see the *real* error if I add `.anonymous().disable()` to my HttpSecurity:

```json
{
   "timestamp":1499452555312,
   "status":401,
   "error":"Unauthorized",
   "message":"An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext",
   "path":"/test"
}
```

---

I investigated this more deeply by increasing the logging verbosity:

```yaml
logging.level:
    org.springframework:
      security: DEBUG
```

This reveals the 10 filters through which my request travels:

```
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 9 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 10 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /test; Attributes: [authenticated]
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:379) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
```

That's what it looks like if Anonymous users are *disabled*. If they're *enabled*: `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` is added into the filter chain just after `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter`, and the sequence ends more like this:

```
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /test at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /test; Attributes: [authenticated]
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@5ff24abf, returned: -1
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
```

Either way: no good.

**Essentially it indicates to me that we are missing some step in the filter chain. We need a filter that would read the header of the ServletRequest, then populate the security context's authentication:**

```kotlin
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(request: HttpServletRequest);
```

I wonder how to get such a filter?

---

This is what my application looks like. It's Kotlin, but hopefully it should make sense to the Java eye.

**Application.kt:**

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses=arrayOf(
        com.example.domain.Package::class,
        com.example.service.Package::class,
        com.example.web.Package::class
))
class MyApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication::class.java, *args)
}
```

**TestController:**

```kotlin
@RestController
class TestController {
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    fun Test(): String {
        return "hey there"
    }
}
```

**MyWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:**

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
/**
 * Based on:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383286/spring-security-custom-userdetailsservice-and-custom-user-class
 *
 * Password encoder:
 * http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database
 */
class MyWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter(
        val userDetailsService: MyUserDetailsService
) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    private val passwordEncoder = BCryptPasswordEncoder()

    override fun userDetailsService() : UserDetailsService {
        return userDetailsService
    }

    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
    }

    @Bean
    fun authenticationProvider() : AuthenticationProvider {
        val authProvider = DaoAuthenticationProvider()
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService())
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
        return authProvider
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity?) {
        http!!
                .anonymous().disable()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
    }
}
```

**MyAuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter:**

```kotlin
/**
 * Based on:
 * https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/tests/annotation/jdbc/src/main/java/demo/Application.java#L68
 */
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
class MyAuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter(
        val auth : AuthenticationManager,
        val dataSource: DataSource,
        val userDetailsService: UserDetailsService

) : AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter() {

    private val passwordEncoder = BCryptPasswordEncoder()

    @Bean
    fun tokenStore(): JdbcTokenStore {
        val tokenStore = JdbcTokenStore(dataSource)
        val oauthAccessTokenTable = "auth_schema.oauth_access_token"
        val oauthRefreshTokenTable = "auth_schema.oauth_refresh_token"
        tokenStore.setDeleteAccessTokenFromRefreshTokenSql("delete from ${oauthAccessTokenTable} where refresh_token = ?")
        tokenStore.setDeleteAccessTokenSql("delete from ${oauthAccessTokenTable} where token_id = ?")
        tokenStore.setDeleteRefreshTokenSql("delete from ${oauthRefreshTokenTable} where token_id = ?")
        tokenStore.setInsertAccessTokenSql("insert into ${oauthAccessTokenTable} (token_id, token, authentication_id, " +
                "user_name, client_id, authentication, refresh_token) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
        tokenStore.setInsertRefreshTokenSql("insert into ${oauthRefreshTokenTable} (token_id, token, authentication) values (?, ?, ?)")
        tokenStore.setSelectAccessTokenAuthenticationSql("select token_id, authentication from ${oauthAccessTokenTable} where token_id = ?")
        tokenStore.setSelectAccessTokenFromAuthenticationSql("select token_id, token from ${oauthAccessTokenTable} where authentication_id = ?")
        tokenStore.setSelectAccessTokenSql("select token_id, token from ${oauthAccessTokenTable} where token_id = ?")
        tokenStore.setSelectAccessTokensFromClientIdSql("select token_id, token from ${oauthAccessTokenTable} where client_id = ?")
        tokenStore.setSelectAccessTokensFromUserNameAndClientIdSql("select token_id, token from ${oauthAccessTokenTable} where user_name = ? and client_id = ?")
        tokenStore.setSelectAccessTokensFromUserNameSql("select token_id, token from ${oauthAccessTokenTable} where user_name = ?")
        tokenStore.setSelectRefreshTokenAuthenticationSql("select token_id, authentication from ${oauthRefreshTokenTable} where token_id = ?")
        tokenStore.setSelectRefreshTokenSql("select token_id, token from ${oauthRefreshTokenTable} where token_id = ?")
        return tokenStore
    }

    override fun configure(security: AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer?) {
        security!!.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
    }

    override fun configure(clients: ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer?) {
        val clientDetailsService = JdbcClientDetailsService(dataSource)
        clientDetailsService.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder)

        val clientDetailsTable = "auth_schema.oauth_client_details"
        val CLIENT_FIELDS_FOR_UPDATE = "resource_ids, scope, " +
                "authorized_grant_types, web_server_redirect_uri, authorities, access_token_validity, " +
                "refresh_token_validity, additional_information, autoapprove"
        val CLIENT_FIELDS = "client_secret, ${CLIENT_FIELDS_FOR_UPDATE}"
        val BASE_FIND_STATEMENT = "select client_id, ${CLIENT_FIELDS} from ${clientDetailsTable}"

        clientDetailsService.setFindClientDetailsSql("${BASE_FIND_STATEMENT} order by client_id")
        clientDetailsService.setDeleteClientDetailsSql("delete from ${clientDetailsTable} where client_id = ?")
        clientDetailsService.setInsertClientDetailsSql("insert into ${clientDetailsTable} (${CLIENT_FIELDS}," +
                " client_id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")
        clientDetailsService.setSelectClientDetailsSql("${BASE_FIND_STATEMENT} where client_id = ?")
        clientDetailsService.setUpdateClientDetailsSql("update ${clientDetailsTable} set " +
                "${CLIENT_FIELDS_FOR_UPDATE.replace(", ", "=?, ")}=? where client_id = ?")
        clientDetailsService.setUpdateClientSecretSql("update ${clientDetailsTable} set client_secret = ? where client_id = ?")
        clients!!.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService)
    }

    override fun configure(endpoints: AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer?) {
        endpoints!!
                .authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
                .authenticationManager(auth)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .approvalStoreDisabled()
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
    }

    @Bean
    protected fun authorizationCodeServices() : AuthorizationCodeServices {
        val codeServices = JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(dataSource)
        val oauthCodeTable = "auth_schema.oauth_code"
        codeServices.setSelectAuthenticationSql("select code, authentication from ${oauthCodeTable} where code = ?")
        codeServices.setInsertAuthenticationSql("insert into ${oauthCodeTable} (code, authentication) values (?, ?)")
        codeServices.setDeleteAuthenticationSql("delete from ${oauthCodeTable} where code = ?")
        return codeServices
    }
}
```

**MyAuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter:**

```kotlin
@Service
class MyUserDetailsService(
        val theDataSource: DataSource
) : JdbcUserDetailsManager() {
    @PostConstruct
    fun init() {
        dataSource = theDataSource

        val usersTable = "auth_schema.users"
        val authoritiesTable = "auth_schema.authorities"

        setChangePasswordSql("update ${usersTable} set password = ? where username = ?")
        setCreateAuthoritySql("insert into ${authoritiesTable} (username, authority) values (?,?)")
        setCreateUserSql("insert into ${usersTable} (username, password, enabled) values (?,?,?)")
        setDeleteUserAuthoritiesSql("delete from ${authoritiesTable} where username = ?")
        setDeleteUserSql("delete from ${usersTable} where username = ?")
        setUpdateUserSql("update ${usersTable} set password = ?, enabled = ? where username = ?")
        setUserExistsSql("select username from ${usersTable} where username = ?")

        setAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username,authority from ${authoritiesTable} where username = ?")
        setUsersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,enabled from ${usersTable} " + "where username = ?")
    }
}
```

---

Any ideas? **Could it be that I need to somehow install the `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` into my filter chain?**

I do get such messages on startup… could these be related to the problem?

```
u.c.c.h.s.auth.MyUserDetailsService      : No authentication manager set. Reauthentication of users when changing passwords will not be performed.
s.c.a.w.c.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$3 : No authenticationProviders and no parentAuthenticationManager defined. Returning null.
```

---

**EDIT:**

It looks like installing `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` is the job of a `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`. I have added the following class:

**MyResourceServerConfigurerAdapter:**

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
class MyResourceServerConfigurerAdapter : ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter()
```

And I confirm in the debugger that this causes `ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer` to enter its `configure(http: HttpSecurity)` method, which *does* look like it tries to install a `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` into the filter chain.

But it doesn't look like it succeeded. According to Spring Security's debug output: I still have the same number of filters in my filter chain. `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` is not in there. What's going on?

---

**EDIT2**: I wonder if the problem is that I have *two* classes (`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`) trying to configure HttpSecurity. Is it mutually exclusive?

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/securing-spring-boot-with-jwts/  this link help you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes! The problem was related to the fact that I had registered *both* a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` **and** a `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`.

Solution: delete the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. And use this `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
class MyResourceServerConfigurerAdapter(
        val userDetailsService: MyUserDetailsService
) : ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {
    private val passwordEncoder = BCryptPasswordEncoder()

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity?) {
        http!!
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
    }

    @Bean
    fun authenticationProvider() : AuthenticationProvider {
        val authProvider = DaoAuthenticationProvider()
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
        return authProvider
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**: In order to get Bearer auth to apply to *all* endpoints (for example the `/metrics` endpoint installed by Spring Actuator), I found that I had to also add `security.oauth2.resource.filter-order: 3` to my `application.yml`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36674892/5257399).