# How to "include" Spring Security configuration into application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to spring security and I was following this example on configuring spring security : https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/. So I saw that they use this method to let the spring know for the configuration.

```
public class SpringWebMvcInitializer extends
   AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { HelloWebSecurityConfiguration.class };
  }
  ...
}
```

But I have app initialization like this:

```
public class AppInit implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(AppConfiguration.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = 
                servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("/services/rest/*");

    }

}
```

And I want to include my spring security configuration there, as without it I get message in browser: Your login attempt was not successful, try again.

Reason: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Comment: Regarding Spring Security: see [my question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44977972/how-to-enable-bearer-authentication-on-spring-boot-application/44978587#44978587); it demonstrates a working implementation of OAuth2 authentication using Bearer tokens and a resource server. I've not included build.gradle, nor have I included the SQL schema & dataset. But hopefully you'll find that code to be a useful reference / starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just register your security config in your AppInit class by changing the line

```
context.register(AppConfiguration.class);
```

to

```
context.register({HelloWebSecurityConfiguration.class, AppConfiguration.class});
```

Comment: Well, that didn't solve my authentication and authorization problem, but I guess that is what I've asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Extend from `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` is a way to make spring to load the security config, but I don't use it. A more convinient way to accomplish this can be like this(decalare the dependency of `spring security` in `pom.xml` first):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER")
                .and().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("USER","ADMIN");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/index").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/message/*").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/index").failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
                .and().rememberMe().tokenValiditySeconds(60*60*7).key("message")
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll();
        // define your action here.
    }

}
```

Spring will load this config automatically on startup for you, this is enough for `spring security` to work. As you see, you should define the rules in `configure(HttpSecurity http)` to tell spring security what to do when a request is coming.