# How to add a specific Header required with a static value in every Request in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, request-headers

In my Spring boot project, I have made some some **RESTful APIs**. Now, for each request in my APIs, I want to set a specific header like below below-

[image]

If the Http request is called with that specific **header name and header value**, only then it will show response code ok(200) otherwise it will show some other response code.

I need one single configuration to fix that specific header for each request in my project. So, I need some suggestion about the procedure to follow to solve this issue.

Comment: maybe this can help , you can use bareer token for your requests https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44977972/how-to-enable-bearer-authentication-on-spring-boot-application

Comment: Just to clarify, are you wanting to validate the header in the req or add a  header to your res? your 1st sentence suggests the former, but the 2nd suggests the latter.

Answer (score 2):

I think in these kind of scenarios if you want to handle them in single point **filters** are good choices

I hope below code can give you the idea how to use filter to solve your problem:

```
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HeaderCheckerFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String header = request.getHeader("MyHeader");
        if (header != null && header.equals("HeaderValue")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            response.getWriter().println("invalid request");
        }
    }
}
```